# Laravel Relationships Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I am fighting this 2 days already. I am trying to set up a relationship and it's not working.

I have a database table "**contracts**" and a column "**status**". And for all rows status is 1

```
id: 1
contract_id: '0005898BC'
status: 1
```

I also have a contract_statuses table with one row:

```
id: 1
status_name: "New status"
```

So the relationship is that contracts table points to the **contract_statuses** table via "status" which is the id in the **contract_statuses** table.

**Here is my code.**

C**ontracts Model:**

```
public function givemestatus()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ContractStatuses');
}
```

**ContractStatuses Model:**

```
public function contract()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Contracts', 'status', 'id');
}
```

**My View:**

```
@foreach ($contracts as $contract)
   {{ $contract->givemestatus->status_name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: You'll have to add the columns into the belongsTo, since you're not using standard column names.

Comment: Oh, how simple that was! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Found an answer thanks to @aynber.
I was missing a foreign key:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ContractStatuses', 'status');
```